# Python decorator to time recursive functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, python-decorators

I have a simple decorator to track the runtime of a function call:

```
def timed(f):
    def caller(*args):
        start = time.time()
        res = f(*args)
        end = time.time()
        return res, end - start
    return caller
```

This can be used as follows, and returns a tuple of the function result and the execution time.

```
@timed
def test(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        pass
    return 0

print(test(900)) # prints (0, 2.69e-05)
```

Simple enough. But now I want to apply this to recursive functions. Applying the above wrapper to a recursive function results in nested tuples with the times of each recursive call, as is expected.

```
@timed
def rec(n):
    if n:
        return rec(n - 1)
    else:
        return 0

print(rec(3)) # Prints ((((0, 1.90e-06), 8.10e-06), 1.28e-05), 1.90e-05)
```

What's an elegant way to write the decorator so that it handles recursion properly? Obviously, you could wrap the call if a timed function:

```
@timed
def wrapper():
    return rec(3)
```

This will give a tuple of the result and the time, but I want all of it to be handled by the decorator so that the caller does not need to worry about defining a new function for every call. Ideas?

Comment: You probably can achieve what you want by using [`sys._getframe`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/sys.html#sys._getframe), but that is an implementation detail of CPython, so it's not really part of the abstract python language. Also it's probably going to be quite slow.

Answer (score 8):

The problem here isn't really the decorator. The problem is that `rec` needs `rec` to be a function that behaves one way, but you want `rec` to be a function that behaves differently. There's no clean way to reconcile that with a single `rec` function.

The cleanest option is to stop requiring `rec` to be two things at once. Instead of using decorator notation, assign `timed(rec)` to a different name:

```
def rec(n):
    ...

timed_rec = timed(rec)
```

If you don't want two names, then `rec` needs to be written to understand the actual value that the decorated `rec` will return. For example,

```
@timed
def rec(n):
    if n:
        val, runtime = rec(n-1)
        return val
    else:
        return 0
```

Comment: Yeah, I guess since the point of the decorator is to be called every time the function is called, it doesn't really fit with recursion by nature.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer the other answers so far (particularly [user2357112's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53232255/1256452)), but you can also make a class-based decorator that detects whether the function has been activated, and if so, bypasses the timing:

```
import time

class fancy_timed(object):
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.f = f
        self.active = False

    def __call__(self, *args):
        if self.active:
            return self.f(*args)
        start = time.time()
        self.active = True
        res = self.f(*args)
        end = time.time()
        self.active = False
        return res, end - start


@fancy_timed
def rec(n):
    if n:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        return rec(n - 1)
    else:
        return 0
print(rec(3))
```

(class written with `(object)` so that this is compatible with py2k and py3k).

Note that to really work properly, the outermost call should use `try` and `finally`.  Here's the fancied up fancy version of `__call__`:

```
def __call__(self, *args):
    if self.active:
        return self.f(*args)
    try:
        start = time.time()
        self.active = True
        res = self.f(*args)
        end = time.time()
        return res, end - start
    finally:
        self.active = False
```

Comment: This has thread-safety and reentrancy issues, though. For example, a call to `rec` in one thread can cause a call in another thread to omit the timing information.

Comment: @user2357112: agreed; that's why I prefer your answer. :-) (It's possible to get the current thread information, so that this cooperates with the `threading` module, but then you hit problems with green threads, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You could structure your timer in a different way by *ahem* abusing the `contextmanager` and `function attribute` a little...

```
from contextlib import contextmanager
import time

@contextmanager
def timed(func):
    timed.start = time.time()
    try:
        yield func
    finally:
        timed.duration = time.time() - timed.start

def test(n):
    for _ in range(n):
        pass
    return n

def rec(n):
    if n:
        time.sleep(0.05) # extra delay to notice the difference
        return rec(n - 1)
    else:
        return n

with timed(rec) as r:
    print(t(10))
    print(t(20))

print(timed.duration)

with timed(test) as t:
    print(t(555555))
    print(t(666666))

print(timed.duration)
```

Results:

```
# recursive
0
0
1.5130000114440918

# non-recursive
555555
666666
0.053999900817871094
```

If this is deemed a bad hack I'll gladly accept your criticism.

Comment: Abusing the attributes of the `timed` function object to store the timing information causes problems if you try to time multiple things at once, though. Also, `timed` doesn't actually need `func`, and isn't really timing the execution of `func`; it's timing the contents of the `with` block.

Comment: In short, bad answer? I'm just learning some of these toolsets recently so I thought this could work, but figured there must be something I'm missing.  Wasn't really thinking of multiple timers though so that's a good point.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not an overall solution to the problem of integrating recursion with decorators, for the problem of timing only, I have verified that the last element of the tuple of the times is the overall run time, as this is the time from the upper-most recursive call. Thus if you had

```
@timed
def rec():
    ...
```

to get the overall runtime given the original function definitions you could simply do

```
rec()[1]
```

Getting the result of the call, on the other hand, would then require recusing through the nested tuple:

```
def get(tup):
    if isinstance(tup, tuple):
        return get(tup[0])
    else:
        return tup
```

This might be too complicated to simply get the result of your function.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue when trying to profile a simple `quicksort` implementation.

**The main issue is that decorators are executed on each function call and we need something that can keep a state**, so we can sum all calls at the end. Decorators are not the right tool the job

However, one idea is to abuse the fact that functions are objects and can have atributes. This is explored below with a simple decorator. Something that must be understood is that, **by using decorator's sintax sugar (`@`), the function will always be accumulating its timings.**

```py
from typing import Any, Callable
from time import perf_counter

class timeit:

    def __init__(self, func: Callable) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.timed = []

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
        start = perf_counter()
        res = self.func(*args, **kwds)
        end = perf_counter()        
        self.timed.append(end - start)
        return res

# usage

@timeit
def rec(n):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = rec(4) # rec result
    print(f"Took {rec.timed:.2f} seconds")
    # Out: Took 3.39 seconds
    result = rec(4) # rec result
    # timings between calls are accumulated
    # Out: Took 6.78 seconds
```

Which brings us to a solution inspired by [@r.ook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53232620/14403987), below is a simple [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) that stores each run timing and prints its sum at the end (`__exit__`). Notice that, because for each timing we require a `with` statement, this will not accumulate different runs.

```py
from typing import Any, Callable
from time import perf_counter

class timeit:

    def __init__(self, func: Callable) -> None:
        self.func = func
        self.timed = []

    def __call__(self, *args: Any, **kwds: Any) -> Any:
        start = perf_counter()
        res = self.func(*args, **kwds)
        end = perf_counter()
        self.timed.append(end - start)
        return res

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback):
        # TODO: report `exc_*` if an exception get raised
        print(f"Took {sum(self.timed):.2f} seconds")
        return

# usage

def rec(n):
    ...

if __name__ == "__main__":

    with timeit(rec) as f:
        result = f(a) # rec result
    # Out: Took 3.39 seconds
```